# Reduce Number of Tick Labels in javafx category axis -Line chart

Tags: java, javafx, linechart

How can I decrease and re-adjust the number of `tick labels` on the `category axis`?

I have a line-chart which takes live data and increases the number of points on x-axis per second which results in too many tick-labels on the x-axis, I want to decrease and readjust those points to max 4-5 keeping all data points.

edit1- I have tried doing them invisible but it increases vertical length of the graph.

Also, It is seen that when I resize the chart shell it reduces the number of tick labels automatically, Where can I see these changes or in which pre-defined classes of the chart APIs

Comment: `CategoryAxis` inherits from `Axis` and that has a [`BooleanProperty autoRanging`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/Axis.html#autoRangingProperty). There are a lot more options which you have to just try out yourself. I think it is fairly well configurable, but I don't really know how and would just try it out myself if I had JavaFX installed right now (unfortunately haven't)...

Comment: Autoranging ranges the labels giving minimum and maximum values of labels on an axis, i want to reduce the number the number of labels showing up on the graph.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.